# Display Ember.Object on the screen in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm green in Ember. I've followed the quickstart and I run those commands:

```
ember new ember-quickstart
ember g route index
```

I've created a basic Ember application with an index route. I've wanted to use this route to display the date on the screen. So I've created some EmberObjects in it.

app/routes/index.js

```
import Object from '@ember/object';
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

function getCompaniesJSON() {
  return [
    {
      "title": "Danone",
      "upvotes": 92,
      "downvotes": 62
    },
    {
      "title": "Bakoma",
      "upvotes": 58,
      "downvotes": 68
    },
    {
      "title": "Zott",
      "upvotes": 62,
      "downvotes": 54
    },
    {
      "title": "Jana",
      "upvotes": 72,
      "downvotes": 56
    }
  ];
}

function totalVotes(company) {
  return company.get('upvotes') + company.get('downvotes');
}

var Company = Object.extend({
  score: function() {
    return (this.get('upvotes') * 100 / totalVotes(this)).toFixed(2);
  }
});

var AppModel = Object.extend({
  topCompanies: function() {
    return this.get('companies').sort(function(a,b) {
      return totalVotes(b) - totalVotes(a);
    }).slice(0, 3);
  }.property('companies.@each.upvotes', 'companies.@each.downvotes')
});

var appModel = AppModel.create({
  companies: getCompaniesJSON().map(function(json) {
    return Company.create(json);
  })
});

export default Route.extend({
  topCompanies: appModel.topCompanies
});
```

app/templates/index.hbs

```
<ul>
{{#each topCompanies}}
  <li>{{title}} {{score}}%</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Above code is displaying nothing. No errors in the console. I'd like to display topCompanies on the screen, but I've no idea how to pass this variable correctly. Is a Route a correct place to do it? Or I should use Component/Controller?

Comment: No, the route is not the right place to define that, as the template doesn't have access to the route's params unless you make it the 'model' or _set them in the controller_ explicitely.

Comment: it could work if you name 'topCompanies' 'model' (then it will be automaticly set to controller's param 'model' and try to access it in template as model instead of topCompanies.

Comment: or you could add `setupController: function(controller, model){
  controller.set('topCompanies', topCompanies);
};` to your route-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is bound to the `controller`, not the `route`. Your `route` however should return the model from the `model` hook.

So you could do something like this:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return appModel.topCompanies
  }
});
```

But then your model its called `model` on your controller and template, not `topCompanies`. to fix this add this to your controller (`ember g controller index`):

```
topCompanies:computed.alias('model')
```

> you can import `computed` with `import {computed} from '@ember/object';`.

---

Next you will have the problem that `score` is not shown. Thats because you declared it as function, not as computed property. So you should change it to this:

```
score: computed('upvotes', 'downvotes', function() {
  return (this.get('upvotes') * 100 / totalVotes(this)).toFixed(2);
}),
```

You also could do this which is identical, however I *strongly recommend against it* because its old syntax:

```
score: function() {
  return (this.get('upvotes') * 100 / totalVotes(this)).toFixed(2);
}.property('upvotes', 'downvotes'),
```

Comment: I still can't make it work. this.get('companies') is undefined. I'm using a controller right now. Can you have a look Lux? I've created separate question for it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586922