# Can't access Ember's class variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

How to properly pass a variable to an Ember's class?

Controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import Object from '@ember/object';

function totalVotes(company) {
  return company.upvotes + company.downvotes;
}

function calcPercent(company) {
    return (company.upvotes * 100 / (company.upvotes + company.downvotes)).toFixed(2);
}

function percentComparator(a, b) {
    return calcPercent(b) - calcPercent(a);
}

var Company = Object.extend({
  score: function() {
    return (this.get('upvotes') * 100 / totalVotes(this)).toFixed(2);
  }.property('upvotes', 'downvotes')
});

var AppModel = Object.extend({
  topCompanies: function() {
    return this.get('companies')
      .sort(percentComparator)
      .slice(0, 8);
  }.property('companies.@each.upvotes', 'companies.@each.downvotes'),
});

var appModel = AppModel.create({
  companies: getCompaniesJSON().map(function(json) {
    return Company.create(json);
  })
});

export default Controller.extend({
  topCompanies: appModel.topCompanies,
});
```

Template:

```
<ul>
{{#each topCompanies as |company|}}
  <li>{{company.title}} {{company.score}}%</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

The result of the above in the browser console:

```
jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

`this.get('companies')` is undefined. Why? I'm passing `companies` to `AppModel.create`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `getCompaniesJSON()` do?

Comment: It returns a list of 100 companies in the below format:
`function getCompaniesJSON() {
  return [
    {
      "title": "Danone",
      "upvotes": 92,
      "downvotes": 62
    },
    {
      "title": "Bakoma",
      "upvotes": 58,
      "downvotes": 68
    }];}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var appModel = AppModel.create({
  companies: getCompaniesJSON().map(function(json) {
    return Company.create(json);
  })
});
```

should something like this (untested):

```
var appModel = AppModel.create({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('companies', getCompaniesJSON().map((json) => {
      return Company.create(json);
    });
  }
});
```

i'm assuming the code is written this way (with global variables) for illustrative purposes and so i will ignore the other issues with the code sample that are likely not present in your real code, such as the property in your controller needing to be a computed.alias instead of direct assignment etc.

Comment: Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super. Error: Assertion Failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.